# Как изменить соотношение сторон экрана игры Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу, чтобы игровая камера имела соотношение сторон экрана 4:3.

Игровой билд может открываться в полном экране, но сама игра будет с таким соотношением сторон экрана.

Подскажите, где и как можно изменять эти настройки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло написание следующего скрипта:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NormalizeScale : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    void Start()
    {
        Screen.SetResolution(1600, 1200, true);
        //Debug.Log("Resolution set to 4:3");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

file > build settings

Где-то там настройки resolution and presentation. Там можна выключить лишние разрешения кроме 4:3

Comment: Это не помогло.

Comment: оно по логике должно помогать в билде, а не в интерфейсе юнити) Это же билд сеттингс, все таки)

Comment: В этом и проблема, что в редакторе все нормально, а вот в билде опять никаких ограничений.